# Load Data from Api to Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Rest API to Snowflake using data factory pipeline. There are no issues with the configuration. However, when I am trying to publish it getting below error.

any inputs?

[image]

Comment: Load the data to a storage account and then copy it in from there?  I think the error gives a pretty good indication of what you should do.

Comment: Got it. It is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin) for pointing in the right direction. Posting it as an answer for the other community members.

As the error suggests, you need to enable the staging when copying the data to or from snowflake if your source or sink is not Blob storage or S3 with the above type of datasets.

Enable the staging and give the staging location like below.

[image]

You need to ensure that the linked service must be a **Blob storage** and not ADLS Gen2.

Also, note that the Authentication mechanism for this linked service should be `SasUriAuthentication`.

[image]